# How to summarize rows based on multiple conditions using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sum, summary

I have the following table:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------+-----+
| Tariff No | Description | Net Weight | Gross Weight | Amount | COO |
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------+-----+
|    900011 |         xyz |         40 |           50 |   1000 |  IT |
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------+-----+
|    900011 |         xyz |         40 |           50 |   1500 |  IT |
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------+-----+
|    400222 |         abc |         50 |           60 |   1000 |  CA |
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------+-----+
|    400222 |         def |         40 |           50 |   2000 |  DE |
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------+-----+
```

I need to summarize this table apropos the columns “Tariff No” and “COO” such that the resulting table is as follows:

```
+-----------+-----+------------+--------------+--------+
| Tariff No | COO | Net Weight | Gross Weight | Amount |
+-----------+-----+------------+--------------+--------+
|    900011 |  IT |         80 |          100 |   2500 |
+-----------+-----+------------+--------------+--------+
|    400222 |  CA |         50 |           60 |   1000 |
+-----------+-----+------------+--------------+--------+
|    400222 |  DE |         40 |           50 |   2000 |
+-----------+-----+------------+--------------+--------+
```

Note that the resulting table doesn't have the “Description” column.

How do I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. At least format your tables so they are readable.

Comment: Hi Hobo.. How about now? I am new to Stackoverflow so I don't really have the access to add tables or images to my question. It has now been edited by Mr. Aadit.. Hope it's clear now. Let me know if you know the solution..

Comment: Thank you Mr. Aadit for your help :)

Comment: Mr. Aadit? No, I am 22 years old and I am not yet married. Just call me Aadit. I wrote an answer to your question. Let me know if that solves your problem and whether you understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do this using JavaScript.

1. First we need to model the table as data in JavaScript:

   ```
   var table = [
       row(900011, "xyz", 40, 50, 1000, "IT"),
       row(900011, "xyz", 40, 50, 1500, "IT"),
       row(400222, "abc", 50, 60, 1000, "CA"),
       row(400222, "def", 40, 50, 2000, "DE")
   ];

   function row( tariffNo
               , description
               , netWeight
               , grossWeight
               , amount
               , coo) {

       return { tariffNo    : tariffNo
              , description : description
              , netWeight   : netWeight
              , grossWeight : grossWeight
              , amount      : amount
              , coo         : coo };
   }
   ```
2. Next, we create a `groupBy` function which categorizes the rows of the given `table` into groups according to the given `groupOf` function:

   ```
   function groupBy(groupOf, table) {
       var groups = {};
       var values = [];

       table.forEach(function (row) {
           var value = groupOf(row);

           if (groups.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
               var rows = groups[value];
           } else {
               var rows = groups[value] = [];
               values.push(value);
           }

           rows.push(row);
       });

       return values.map(getGroup);

       function getGroup(value) {
           return groups[value];
       }
   }
   ```
3. Then, we group the input table according to “Tariff No” and “COO” as follows:

   ```
   var groups = groupBy(groupOf, table);

   function groupOf(row) {
       return row.tariffNo + " " + row.coo;
   }
   ```
4. Finally, we summarize the result using the following `map`/`reduce` operation:

   ```
   var result = groups.map(summarize);

   function summarize(rows) {
       return rows.reduce(summary, { netWeight   : 0
                                   , grossWeight : 0
                                   , amount      : 0 });
   }

   function summary(sum, row) {
       return { tariffNo    : row.tariffNo
              , coo         : row.coo
              , netWeight   : sum.netWeight   + row.netWeight
              , grossWeight : sum.grossWeight + row.grossWeight
              , amount      : sum.amount      + row.amount };
   }
   ```

That's all. Putting it all together:

```js
var table = [
    row(900011, "xyz", 40, 50, 1000, "IT"),
    row(900011, "xyz", 40, 50, 1500, "IT"),
    row(400222, "abc", 50, 60, 1000, "CA"),
    row(400222, "def", 40, 50, 2000, "DE")
];

var groups = groupBy(groupOf, table);

var result = groups.map(summarize);

alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));

function row( tariffNo
            , description
            , netWeight
            , grossWeight
            , amount
            , coo) {

    return { tariffNo    : tariffNo
           , description : description
           , netWeight   : netWeight
           , grossWeight : grossWeight
           , amount      : amount
           , coo         : coo };
}

function groupBy(groupOf, table) {
    var groups = {};
    var values = [];

    table.forEach(function (row) {
        var value = groupOf(row);

        if (groups.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
            var rows = groups[value];
        } else {
            var rows = groups[value] = [];
            values.push(value);
        }

        rows.push(row);
    });

    return values.map(getGroup);

    function getGroup(value) {
        return groups[value];
    }
}

function groupOf(row) {
    return row.tariffNo + " " + row.coo;
}

function summarize(rows) {
    return rows.reduce(summary, { netWeight   : 0
                                , grossWeight : 0
                                , amount      : 0 });
}

function summary(sum, row) {
    return { tariffNo    : row.tariffNo
           , coo         : row.coo
           , netWeight   : sum.netWeight   + row.netWeight
           , grossWeight : sum.grossWeight + row.grossWeight
           , amount      : sum.amount      + row.amount };
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Aadit ! :).. Will this work if the data of table1 is dynamic?